# How to support multiple domain links to open home screen app for flutter web pwa?

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, deep-linking, flutter-web, manifest.json

[image: In the Image you can see that we have multiple domains as firebase default domains can't be shut down.]

Problem is that when user installs the home screen app from google form a link such as wen-el-sahra.web.app and then a link such as wen-el-sahra.web.app/home is clicked it opens in home screen app but if wen-el-sahra.firebaseapp.com/home is clicked it doesnot open in homescreen app. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug or a problem to circumvent. Instead it has to be handled inside the app to work on the same origin. For a detailed explanation on why this is not the case please read this [article on multi-orign-pwas](https://web.dev/multi-origin-pwas/).

So I would suggest to work with only one domain or as in the above mentioned article request user permission to register each sub-domain while installing the PWA initially, if this is possible.

I assume you are using firebase hosting. So always works with the available registered domain. That way there is no need to expose the `web.app` and `firebaseapp.com` domains to the users. In this case always work with `wenelsahra.com`

Comment: Yes Indeed I am using firebase hosting. Thanks for the answer. I will keep in mind your suggestion